# How to get output of gradle --debug in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a way to get tasks' debug output from when Android Studio is running a task? Any task?

in CLI it's `./gradlew task --debug`. How to achieve the same result in AS?

Comment: You can use the command line also inside AS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are compiler options to add additional flags:

[image: Compiler options]

Comment: Ohh `--profile` now that's an interesting feature that's not well promoted.  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:profiling_build